# AppEngine processing my POST requests as GET

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, post, web.xml

I encountered a weird stuff and I've been struggling with it for a while now. Google AppEngine is processing my POST requests as GET. I've tried 3 different REST clients and they produced the same error (an html document that said GET is not available for the specified URL; but for God's sake I sent a POST!). 
I'm using Java, and I've set the web.xml file correctly. Please note that this is not the first servlet in the project that responds to POST and others have worked properly. To complicate matters, this same servlet responds to POST normally when I run the app on my local development appengine server. I've cleaned and rebuilt the project several times and even changed the URL of the servlet but the problem still persists. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common reason for this is that your POST is redirected for some reason, and redirects are always GET. What does the logging console say?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer gave me a wonderful hint. I mapped myname.com to www.myname.com so I guess the redirect reached the actual target as a GET. It worked fine when I specified it fully. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

I was using the non secure url and it redirects POST to GET. Using https fixed this.